# Measure code/node running time

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running `amcl` package for offline data and I want measure its running time, Is there something like MATLAB's `tic` and `toc` command[?](http://matlab.com)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166286/measure-code/node-running-time/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but [Tic Toc in C++](http://www.timzaman.com/?p=2246).

You could add in your amcl node.

EDIT : I had to use something similar myself and realize the link in made for windows. Here is what you're suppose to use on linux : [Clock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::WallTime can be used as follows

```
ros::WallTime start_, end_;

start_ = ros::WallTime::now();

// **** do something here... ****

end_ = ros::WallTime::now();

// print results
double execution_time = (end_ - start_).toNSec() * 1e-6;
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Exectution time (ms): " << execution_time);
```

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6